# Sucess message is not getting displayed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, message

I want to show a success message once the email is sent after redirected to same page. Here is my code :

```
return redirect('currentshowreport?showid='.$show_id)->with('success','Email sent successfully');
```

I am getting redirected to the specified page but the success message is not getting displayed. How to achieve this?

Comment: Where you display the message ?

Comment: I am displaying the message on the same page where i have a button "Send email". After clicking on this button i want to send an email also want to display success message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```